# Android Load JSON and Passing Data to View

Tags: android, json

Guys

I Am Trying Getting JSONData to ListView

it's Works fine,, but the problem is i Want pass the json data for each row to next view

Here's, My JSON Class

```
public class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<JSONFields>> {

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<JSONFields> doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                String url = params[0];
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
                HttpResponse response;
                response = client.execute(get);
                InputStream content = response.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedReader reader;
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;
                String json = "";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    json += line;
                }

                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);
                ArrayList<JSONFields> alData = new ArrayList<JSONFields>();
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {


                    obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    data = new JSONFields();
                    data.setID(obj.getString("id"));
                    data.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                    data.setImage(obj.getString("image"));
                    data.setYoutube(obj.getString("youtube"));
                    data.setLength(obj.getString("length"));

                    alData.add(data);
                }
                System.out.println("Data returned sucessfully");
                return alData;

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<JSONFields> result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainApp.this, result);

            listview.setAdapter(adapter);


        }
    }
```

and I have Create Class for Holding JSON Data Fields

here it is

public class JSONFields {

```
private String id;
private String title;


public String getID() {
    return id;
}
public void setID(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;

}
```

but when I pass with this code

```
    String thetitle = data.getTitle();

    Intent showView = new Intent(MainApp.this, Show.class);

    showView.putExtra("title", thetitle);

    startActivity(showView);
```

I get only the last row info..

that's my problem

I want if I clicked the row 5 see the attr of row 5 in show View

I am new to Java and android

and I think I should add the position to getTitle(position)

when getting< because in iOS dev, I pass the data of array objectAtIndex:int to NSDic

that's all

but here< I don't know

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use onItemClickListener to get the position of clicked view,
And than you can get the same object from the list or from array which you have set to adapter.

Comment: amm how I can use that.. Yaa I want item Clicked on ListView